# directory not listing on web-browser for ftp server

Tags: 12.04, ftp, vsftpd

I have used vsftpd to create FTP server.I am using Ubuntu 12.04 desktop version.the problem is that when I hit the `ftp: //myservername/` on the browser it shows only

Index of /
Name    Size    Date Modified

not listing any files and not asking user name and password.

when I use `ftp: //username:password@myservername/` its listing directories. but I don't want to write user name and password in the address bar. so how do I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have the server configured to require authentication to see those files. You will need to configure the server to allow anonymous authentication.